# making css more fluid at different sizes

Tags: css, html, stretch

I recreated the issue at http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5d8/

I have a background div that is 100% wide and 200 pixels high, and a minimum width of 600 pixels. Inside it I have five floated divs.

Is it possible to have the width of the background div expand to cover the floated divs as the width of the layout changes?

Any assistance would be really appreciated!

```
#stripe {
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
min-width:600px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
background-image: url(http://signaturewebdesign.net/egro14/14_images/brown_stripe_bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.holder {
float: left;
height: 200px;
width: 125px;
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 13px;
padding-left: 12px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: why not set .holder's width and height as a percentage?

Comment: the images within the holder div are a set width, and appear on more than one line as the screen size reduces, but the stripe does not expand with them

Comment: you can use `.holder img { max-width:100%; width:100% height:100;}` to make the images responsively display themselves fully, in the correct aspect ratio, with any sized layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like the height to change when the items occupying more then one line, you could add `overflow:hidden` and set `height` to `auto` in for your `#stripe` style:

```
#stripe {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-width:600px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://signaturewebdesign.net/egro14/14_images/brown_stripe_bg.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5d8/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5d8/6/

```
.holder { width:15%;}
.holder img { max-width:100%; width:100% height:100;}
```

You can use to make the images responsively display themselves fully, in the correct aspect ratio, with any sized layout.

Comment: I see what you are geting at, that would change the width of the actual graphics and keep them on the same line. It works good, but I want to try keep the images at a set width. I really appreciate your answer, thank you I am sure I can use this way in the future on other projects

Comment: @BillTeale no problem, I'm glad you found an answer!